# my apps full logo in my admob account doesn't display...just android default logo

Tags: android, admob

I have a published app on play store and am done integrating. Admob ads displays perfectly fine but I can't get to see my apps full logo in my admob account. I have waited for almost a week yet no new development, no impressions, no stats, nothing. Why does this happen? Please can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it.
It won't affect anything.